# socket.io on nodejs server behind nginx reverse proxy not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

My nodejs (14.x) server has `socket.io 4.4.1` installed. The server is running behind reverse proxy server. Here is the code in server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    //origin: "h-t-t-p-s://mydomain.com" //for production
  }
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("socket established ", socket.id);
}
```

In dev, the socket was established successfully.

Test the production server connection with server IP address (not domain name) by following [doc](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/) and it was timeout:

```
curl "h-t-t-p://serverip:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
curl: (28) Failed to connect to serverip port 5000: Operation timed out
```

The nginx proxy server is configured by following [doc](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/):

```
location /sokt {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
```

On React Native 0.66 front end with `socket.io-client 4.3.2` with JWT token access to the nodejs server above, here is the socket.io code :

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
useEffect(() => {
   //init socket
    let socUrl = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/sokt`;  //domain name on production proxy server 
    console.log("socUrl : ", socUrl);
    let _socket = io(socUrl);  
    //
    console.log("socket connected : ", _socket);
    _socket.on("connect", () => { //<<==this line throw error below
      console.log("socket.id in chat : ", _socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
    });
})
```

But the it throws error with `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Here is the console output for the socket on client side. The output says `connected: false, disconnected:true`. Event of `socket.on("connect"...)` was never fired:

```
socket connected :  {"acks": {}, "connected": false, "disconnected": true, "flags": {}, "ids": 0, "io": {"_autoConnect": true, "_callbacks": {"$close": [Array], "$error": [Array], "$open": [Array], "$packet": [Array]}, "_randomizationFactor": 0.5, "_readyState": "opening", "_reconnection": true, "_reconnectionAttempts": Infinity, "_reconnectionDelay": 1000, "_reconnectionDelayMax": 5000, "_timeout": 20000, "backoff": {"attempts": 0, "factor": 2, "jitter": 0.5, "max": 5000, "ms": 1000}, "clearTimeoutFn": [Function bound clearTimeout], "decoder": {}, "encoder": {}, "engine": {"_callbacks": [Object], "clearTimeoutFn": [Function bound clearTimeout], "hostname": "mydomain.com", "id": null, "opts": [Object], "pingInterval": null, "pingTimeout": null, "pingTimeoutTimer": null, "port": "443", "prevBufferLen": 0, "readyState": "opening", "secure": true, "setTimeoutFn": [Function bound setTimeout], "transport": [XHR], "transports": [Array], "upgrades": null, "writeBuffer": [Array]}, "nsps": {"/sokt": [Circular]}, "opts": {"hostname": "mydomain.com", "path": "/socket.io", "port": "443", "secure": true}, "setTimeoutFn": [Function bound setTimeout], "skipReconnect": false, "subs": [[Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy]], "uri": "h-t-t-p-s://mydomain.com/sokt"}, "nsp": "/sokt", "receiveBuffer": [], "sendBuffer": [], "subs": [[Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy]]}
```

UPDATE:
Event `connect_error` was fired and here is the output of socket (how to see the error message):

```
 LOG  socket connect_error :  {"_callbacks": {"$connect": [[Function anonymous]], "$connect_error": [[Function anonymous]], "$disconnect": [[Function anonymous]]}, "acks": {}, "connected": false, "disconnected": true, "flags": {}, "ids": 0, "io": {"_autoConnect": true, "_callbacks": {"$close": [Array], "$error": [Array], "$open": [Array], "$packet": [Array]}, "_randomizationFactor": 0.5, "_readyState": "closed", "_reconnecting": true, "_reconnection": true, "_reconnectionAttempts": Infinity, "_reconnectionDelay": 1000, "_reconnectionDelayMax": 5000, "_timeout": 20000, "backoff": {"attempts": 30, "factor": 2, "jitter": 0.5, "max": 5000, "ms": 1000}, "clearTimeoutFn": [Function bound clearTimeout], "decoder": {}, "encoder": {}, "engine": {"_callbacks": [Object], "clearTimeoutFn": [Function bound clearTimeout], "hostname": "my domain.com", "id": null, "opts": [Object], "pingInterval": null, "pingTimeout": null, "pingTimeoutTimer": null, "port": "443", "prevBufferLen": 0, "readyState": "opening", "secure": true, "setTimeoutFn": [Function bound setTimeout], "transport": [XHR], "transports": [Array], "upgrades": null, "writeBuffer": [Array]}, "nsps": {"/sokt": [Circular]}, "opts": {"hostname": "mydomain.com", "path": "/socket.io", "port": "443", "secure": true}, "setTimeoutFn": [Function bound setTimeout], "skipReconnect": false, "subs": [], "uri": "h-t-t-p-s://mydomain.com/sokt"}, "nsp": "/sokt", "receiveBuffer": [], "sendBuffer": [], "subs": [[Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy], [Function subDestroy]]}
```

UPDATE1:nginx access log:

```
xx.xx.131.199 - - [18/Feb/2022:06:46:36 +0800] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ny9tQRW HTTP/1.1" 404 53 "-" "okhttp/4.9.1" "-""127.0.0.1:8545" "127.0.0.1:8545""-" "http_authorization"
```

The odd is that the `127.0.0.1:8545` which is another route handled by reverse proxy for . It shall be `127.0.0.1:5000` for `socket.io` and we didn't see it here. Is that something smell?

Comment: There is a `.` in the line throwing the error: `() => {.`

Comment: Also a socket has the following events you add handlers for to get error details `connect_error`, `connect_timeout`, `reconnect`, `reconnect_attempterr`, `reconnecting`, `reconnect_error`, `reconnect_failed`